# ControlTemplate.Resources in a code-behind file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, wpf-controls

How can I get a named resource from ControlTemplate in a code-behind file (*.xaml.cs)? TryFindResource returns null. Template property of the control is also null. What else should I try?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean on server side? Is this an XBAP? WPF itself doesn't really have anything to do with server-side technology.

Comment: I've mistaken. Haven’t been precise, just was using term from ASP.NET. I meant in code-behind file. NOT in XAML!

Comment: Jist fixed it in the question. Thanks!

Comment: this would seem to be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783620/how-would-i-access-this-wpf-xaml-resource-programmatically/3783819#3783819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using custom control?
If yes, you can override OnApplyTemplate method in custom control and can use  `Template.Find("name of resource")`
then expose it as a property from the control.

if No, then use custom control.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you control that is derived from Control class? If so, yes it is derived from it. Thank you for OnApplyTemplate clue. Although Template doesn't contain Find method, I still able to access resources via Tempate.Resources["name of resource"]. That's fine. BUT. My problem is that I need to access it in private static void OnCategoryNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) methodd which is called whenever someone changes Category dependency property. Depending on category I should change the control's background.

Comment: This method is called even when I'm setting values of Category property first time (in XAML markup), but by that time OnApplyTemplate hasn't been fired, i.e. template hasn't been probably applied yet, so Template property returns null :(. Is there any workaround here? I think I'm kind of missing a point here...

Comment: @Bashir Magomedov: you can derive custom control from control class or any derived class. In your case, you have to do the same thing that you are doing in OnCategoryNameChanged handler, from OnApplyTemplate as well. In OnCategoryNameChanged handler, check if Template is applied otherwise do the same stuff in OnApplyTemplate. You may need to use some private variables in your class to keep track on this.

Comment: Thanks! That might be a solution, but I think that I really missed such feature as Triggers. I replaced my OnCategoreNameChanged handler with bunch of triggers in XAML! Any way thank you!