# referencing a xaml control by name in the xaml code, instead of in C#?

Tags: xaml, controls, reference, expression-blend

I just realized how amazing Xaml is (usually I just design UIs in visual studio). I am using Expression Blend to do all my work, and am not sure whether or not I can do something.

I was watching a tutorial on youtube, about creating animations, and would like to do something a little different. It has to do with increasing and reducing the opacity of an ellise. The code in question:

```
<Canvas.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="brighter">
        <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="0.1" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.25"
        />              
    </Storyboard>       
    <Storyboard x:Key="dimmer">
        <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.25"
        />              
    </Storyboard>       
</Canvas.Resources>
```

What I want is, instead of 'From="0.1"' and 'To="0.1"', I want it to either start from, or go to the current opacity value of the ellipse

so like:

```
From=ellipse.Opacity To='1.0'
```

But I dont know if you can do this in Xaml (my guess is that you cannot). Can you reference a xaml control within xaml itself?

Thanks

***EDIT***

for anyone else looking for the solution, use Bindings....so instead of:

```
From="0.1"
```

use

```
From="{Binding ellipse.Opacity}" <!--ellipse is the name of the control you are referencing-->
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783620/how-would-i-access-this-wpf-xaml-resource-programmatically on how to access WPF resources from code

Comment: as far as I can tell, he is accessing the element in c#...I want to be able to reference an object in the Xaml code itself

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. You can use bindings just like anywhere else and use the ElementName property in the Binding to reference another (named) control.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok. I will go read about bindings! thanks :)

Comment: oh wow, that was easy lol...got it working!

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you add your solutions for others to learn from. You can even accept your own answer after a little delay

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you should be able to remove the "from" properties. That way the animation always run from the current value to the value specified.
Something like:

```
<Canvas.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="brighter">
    <DoubleAnimation
         Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
  </Storyboard>
  <Storyboard x:Key="dimmer">
    <DoubleAnimation
         Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
  </Storyboard>
</Canvas.Resources>
```